# Is it possible to display the small button to change the map type using Android and Maps fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps

When using Google Maps on the bottom left you have an icon to change the map type, I want to add this functionnality to my small Android application but I can't figure out how.

Here is what I have:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        getLastLocation();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        // different types of maps
      /*  mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);*/

    }
```

I tried to check the getUiSettings but it seems like there isn't an option for that ? (which I find a bit strange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple :)

**Use FAB in your map XML File like this:**

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="#0D640B"
    app:elevation="20dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:rippleColor="#0D640B"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_map_type" />
```

**Then add this lines in your Map Activity:**

```
  FloatingActionButton fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL == mMap.getMapType()) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            } else {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }
```